# Sinon - spy not being called but test enters into the function

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, express, sinon

I made the test for the function with two stubs, actually stubs are working, and if I console.log res.json or next in any part of the function it shows the spy objects inside. Anyway the spy is not being called, when I make the assertion it says "expected spy to have been called at least once but was never called". The program works, but the test is crazy. Help me please!

I have function like this:

```
export function createOrUpdateToken(req, res, next) {
  const { code, redirect_uri, realm_id, quickbooksAuth } = req.body;

  if (!code || !redirect_uri || !realm_id) {
    const message = 'Authorization code, Redirect URI and Realm Id are required';
    return next(new CustomError('Bad Request', message, 400));
  }
  return issueRefreshTokenBasedOnAuthorizationCode(
    {
      redirect_uri,
      authorizationCode: code,
      authorization: quickbooksAuth,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const { body: { refresh_token } } = response;
      return securityModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { realmId: realm_id },
        { refreshToken: refresh_token },
        { upsert: true },
        (err) => {
          if (err) return next(err);
          return res.json('Authentication successfull');
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return next(err);
    });
}
```

And the test is like this:

```
it('Should create or update token', () => {
  req.body = {
    code: '1234',
    redirect_uri: 'www.test.com',
    realm_id: '12345',
    quickbooksAuth: 'dhajksdas.dsajdosaiudjsa.dsaojpdas'
  };
  sinon
    .stub(intuit, 'issueRefreshTokenBasedOnAuthorizationCode')
    .resolves({
      body: {
        refresh_token: 'hjdklasdashda.dsa.dasdsa.dasddasdas'
      }
    });

  sinon
    .stub(securityModel, 'findOneAndUpdate')
    .withArgs({ realmId: req.body.realm_id },
      { refreshToken: 'hjdklasdashda.dsa.dasdsa.dasddasdas' })
    .yields(null);
  createOrUpdateToken(req, res, next);
  sinon.assert.called(res.json);
});
```

The conditions are:

```
beforeEach(() => {
      res = {
        json: sinon.spy()
      };
      next = sinon.spy();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      sinon.restore();
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue

`createOrUpdateToken` executes some asynchronous code which hasn't finished by the time it returns and `sinon.assert.called(res.json)` runs and fails.

### Solution

You are already returning a Promise from `createOrUpdateToken` so just make your test an `async` test and `await` the Promise before running the assertion:

```js
it('Should create or update token', async () => {  // make the test function async
  req.body = {
    code: '1234',
    redirect_uri: 'www.test.com',
    realm_id: '12345',
    quickbooksAuth: 'dhajksdas.dsajdosaiudjsa.dsaojpdas'
  };
  sinon
    .stub(intuit, 'issueRefreshTokenBasedOnAuthorizationCode')
    .resolves({
      body: {
        refresh_token: 'hjdklasdashda.dsa.dasdsa.dasddasdas'
      }
    });

  sinon
    .stub(securityModel, 'findOneAndUpdate')
    .withArgs({ realmId: req.body.realm_id },
      { refreshToken: 'hjdklasdashda.dsa.dasdsa.dasddasdas' })
    .yields(null);
  await createOrUpdateToken(req, res, next);  // await the returned Promise
  sinon.assert.called(res.json);  // SUCCESS
});
```